# Book request for Z-Transform

Tags: z-transform, reference-request, books

I am at the moment self studying Z-Transform. I need some references on this subject with some applications ( electrical circuits or else). What are good references on this subject. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the best book that relates circuits to the z-transform is Papoulis, "Circuits and Systems: A Modern Approach". You can find it used for a handful of dollars.

Comment: Thanls Mbaz for the reference. Does it have solved exercices ?

Comment: It doesn't, but it does have plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mbaz ...I will try to buy it.